# Efficiently run a function on many columns in a data table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table which has a series of columns that make up the key and then a large number of other numeric columns. I have a separate vector that is the same length as each column and I would like to replace each column with the product of that other vector and the original column. I'm having trouble figuring out a way to efficiently do this. I can do this column by column--

```
data <- data.table(id1=c("a","a","b","b"), id2=c("c","d","c","d"), var1=1:4, var2=5:8,   var3=9:12)
setkeyv(data, c("id1", "id2"))
x <- c(10, 100, 1000, 10000)
data$var1 <- data[,var1 * x] 
data
```

--but I will eventually have hundreds of these variables. Also, the number of columns is itself variable, so it'd be nice to have some way loop over the columns without having to call them by name. This seemed promising:

```
data <- data[,lapply(list(var2, var3), function(y) y*x)]
data
```

but doing this drops the columns used as the key, which I'd like to keep, and also still requires that I list out all the variable names. The data frame equivalent of what I'm looking for is something like:

```
data <- data.frame(id1=c("a","a","b","b"), id2=c("c","d","c","d"), var1=1:4, var2=5:8, var3=9:12)
for (var in grep("var", names(data))) data[,var] <- x*data[,var]
data
```

Comment: Normally I would do this sort of thing by creating a whole other data frame/matrix that consists only of the column you're multiplying by and then just using vectorized multiplication, and assigning it back to the relevant columns. Using matrices, that will be very fast.

Answer (score 4):

1) Try this:

```
> data[ , .SD * x[.I], by = list( id1, id2 ) ]
   id1 id2  var1  var2   var3
1:   a   c    10    50     90
2:   a   d   200   600   1000
3:   b   c  3000  7000  11000
4:   b   d 40000 80000 120000
```

2) or this by-without-by variation:

```
> setkey(data, id1, id2 )
> data[ J( id1, id2 ), .SD * x[.I] ]
   id1 id2  var1  var2   var3
1:   a   c    10    50     90
2:   a   d   200   600   1000
3:   b   c  3000  7000  11000
4:   b   d 40000 80000 120000
```

3) or this:

```
> data[, cbind( id1, id2, .SD[, !c("id1", "id2")] * x )]
  id1 id2  var1  var2   var3
1   a   c    10    50     90
2   a   d   200   600   1000
3   b   c  3000  7000  11000
4   b   d 40000 80000 120000
```