# How to apply a summary function to multiple columns of a data table

Tags: r, data.table

First off, let's fake some data

```
>library(data.table)
>DT = data.table(x=c('A','A','B','B'),y=c('X','Y','X','Y'),z=c(1,2,3,4))
>DT
   x y z
1: A X 1
2: A Y 2
3: B X 3
4: B Y 4
>DF<-data.frame(DT)
>DF
  x y z
1 A X 1
2 A Y 2
3 B X 3
4 B Y 4
cols<-cbind('x','y')
> DF[,cols]
  x y
1 A X
2 A Y
3 B X
4 B Y
> lapply(X=DF[,cols],FUN=paste,sep=', ',collapse=', ')
$x
[1] "A, A, B, B"

$y
[1] "X, Y, X, Y"
```

This feels like it should be really simple. How do I do that apply with DT? I'm trying to stick with data.frame so that I can run this on very large data sets (n > 1 mil). The closest I've been able to come has been:

```
> DT[,lapply(X=list(get(cols)),FUN=paste,sep=', ',collapse=', ')]
           V1
1: A, A, B, B
```

It's only applying the function to the first of the two columns I specified.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficiently run a function on many columns in a data table in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659887/efficiently-run-a-function-on-many-columns-in-a-data-table-in-r)

Comment: Just a small note, you could convert between data frame and data table using setDT (convert to DT) and setDF (convert to DF) in data.table package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
as.list(DT[, lapply(.SD, paste, collapse = ","), .SDcols = c('x','y')])
#$x
#[1] "A,A,B,B"
#
#$y
#[1] "X,Y,X,Y"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, toString), .SDcols = c("x", "y")]
            x          y
## 1: A, A, B, B X, Y, X, Y
```